# Regex to extract categories/sub-categories from urls with python

Tags: python, regex, url, categories

I have urls to parse of the form:

```
www.my-journal.com/category/sub-category/sub-sub-category/title
www.my-journal.com/category/sub-category/sub-sub-category
www.my-journal.com/category/sub-category/
www.my-journal.com/category/
www.my-journal.com
```

with changing categories, sub-categories and sub-sub-categories.

What regex can I use to extract the categories, the subcategories, and the sub-sub-categories when they exist? Is there a better way to be able to use these variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just split the string at `/`

```
categories = url.split('/')[1:]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> txt = 'www.my-journal.com/category/sub-category/sub-sub-category/title'
>>> re.findall(r'/[^/]*', txt)
['/category', '/sub-category', '/sub-sub-category', '/title']
```

if there only up-to 3 levels, then maybe:

```
>>> iter = re.finditer(r'/([^/]*)', txt)
>>> for _, m in zip(range(3), iter):
...     print(m.group(1))
... 
category
sub-category
sub-sub-category
```